Create a string with Variables but without the quotation marks around the variable
I have looked through some examples on here but nothing seems to quite fit what I need.
I need to take the variable DeptVar = "E22E27E33" (this is the result from the userform)
and turn it into this [Department] = "E22" and so on.
The problem I am having is getting the quotation marks around the Department (E22)
Here is my code. I have tried every variation that i can think of to get it to add the quotations.
Sub CreateString ()
Dim Index as Integer
Dim DeptVar as String
Dim DeptString as String

DeptVar = "E22E27E33" ' <---This is how it is gathered from the userform
Index = 1

Do While Index < 8
    If DeptString = "" Then
     DeptString = "[Department] = " & "" Mid(DeptVar, index, 3) & ""
Else: DeptString = DeptString & "," " AND [Department = " & Mid, index, 3)

end if

index = index +3

loop

end Sub

It currently returns this:
[Department] = E22, AND [Department] = E27, AND [Department] = E33

I need it to return this:
[Department] = "E22", AND [Department] = "E27", AND [Department] = "E33"


chr(34) & deptString & chr(34)?

Or double up the quotes.

Sub CreateString()

    Const TMPL = "[Department] = ""###"""
    Dim DeptVar As String, DeptString As String, i As Long, s As String
    
    DeptVar = "E22E27E33" ' <---This is how it is gathered from the userform
    
    For i = 1 To Len(DeptVar) Step 3
        DeptString = DeptString & s & Replace(TMPL, "###", Mid(DeptVar, i, 3))
        s = ", AND "
    Next
    Debug.Print DeptString
  
End Sub


Build a String
Sub CreateString()

    Const CODE_LEN As Long = 3
    
    Dim DeptCodes As String: DeptCodes = "E22E27E33" ' <--- from the userform
    
    Dim i As Long, DeptString As String, CodeString As String
    Dim IsFirstFound As Boolean
    
    For i = 1 To Len(DeptCodes) Step CODE_LEN
        CodeString = "[Department] = """ & Mid(DeptCodes, i, CODE_LEN) & """"
        If IsFirstFound Then
            DeptString = DeptString & ", AND " & CodeString
        Else
            DeptString = CodeString
            IsFirstFound = True
        End If
    Next i

    Debug.Print DeptString

End Sub


Thank you. I will look through this because there are things in here that a new to me. Well, just about everything is new to me....lol. I wish there was a comprehensive guide for these functions. the Microsoft answers dont make a whole lot of sense to me. I feel like they dont give enough information.

"" Returns an empty string.  Doubling double quotes are converted to single sets of double quotes.  Examples: """" is converted to ", """E2""" returns "E2".  Use Chr(34) to return " as an alternative.
Sub CreateString()
    Dim Index As Integer
    Dim DeptVar As String
    Dim DeptString As String

    DeptVar = "E22E27E33" ' <---This is how it is gathered from the userform
    Index = 1

    Do While Index < 8
        If DeptString = "" Then
            DeptString = "[Department] = " & Chr(34) & Mid(DeptVar, Index, 3) & Chr(34)
        Else
            DeptString = DeptString & "," & Chr(34) & " AND [Department] = " & Chr(34) & Mid(DeptVar, Index, 3)
        End If

        Index = Index + 3

    Loop

End Sub

I would avoid the loop if we are always getting back a 9 character string:
Sub CreateString2()
    
    Dim DeptVar As String
    Dim DeptString As String

    DeptVar = "E22E27E33" ' <---This is how it is gathered from the userform
    DeptString = "[Department] = " & Chr(34) & Left(DeptVar, 3) & Chr(34) & _
    " AND [Department] = " & Chr(34) & Mid(DeptVar, 4, 3) & Chr(34) & _
    " AND [Department] = " & Chr(34) & Mid(DeptVar, 7, 3) & Chr(34)

End Sub

The Immediate Window is a great way to test code like this.


Awesome...thanks...im pretty sure I tried it that way but I must have had something wrong. I I obviously did otherwise I would be asking the question....lol. I loke the no loop idea.

Thanks @CDP1802.  i forgot to copy the final code from the Immediate window.

also, thanks for the tip about the immediate window  i figured there had to be a way to use that better!

Assuming identical department abbreviations (e.g. "E"), but even varying lengths of dept numbers you might try the following function combining Split & Join:
Function dept(ByVal DeptVar As String, Optional ByVal letter As String = "E") As String
    Const prefix = """, AND "
    Const pattern = "[Department] = """
    Dim a: a = Split(DeptVar, letter)
    dept = Mid(Join(a, prefix & pattern & letter), Len(prefix) + 1) & Chr(34)
End Function

Example call
    Dim DeptVar As String
    DeptVar = "E22E27E33"
    Debug.Print dept(DeptVar)

Result in VB Editor's immediate window
[Department] = "E22", AND [Department] = "E27", AND [Department] = "E33"

